# Java: comparing two Objects of different type with same value, returning true

Tags: java, object, compare

I have some data I need to compare. It's possible I might have to compare values with different data types. Here is what is basically happening:

```
Object a = (long) 1;
Object b = (int) 1;


System.out.println(Objects.equals(a, b)); //returns false

Sysout.out.println(Objects.equals(a.toString(), b.toString())); //returns true
```

Does using .toString() seem like a viable solution? Or should I go another route ?

Edit:

This program is reading from HIVE tables which some tables might have the exact same data in it, but different datatypes. Datatypes include int, smallint, bigint, string, array, double, timestamp.

I'm not concerned with the Array comparison, because there's nothing other than the array type that can hold an array. However, it is possible for String types to be compared with timestamp. I'm also not concerned with int to double comparisons either, because these should result in false.

Any numerical value with no decimal places and different datatypes should be compared with their value and datatype mismatch should not return false.

Edit:

Any number with decimals will be rounded with 3 decimal places before comparison.

Comment: Do you have just integer/long or float/double too?

Comment: yes that's a possibility. It can also be String or ArrayList types. But in those instances it will only be a String-to-String comparison or ArrayList-to-ArrayList comparison.

Comment: Based on that informations, the question is a little too broad. Maybe you can edit the question and explain what you are trying to do and which possibilities you considered for solving your issue? You could provide some input data and explain what you should do with it and how you are trying to accomplish the task

Comment: what kind of class or object this `Objects` is ?? confused

Comment: Note: `new BigDecimal("1.0")` and `new BigDecimal("1.00")` are not equal even if you `toString` first.

Comment: @VikrantKashyap https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html

Comment: @PeterLawrey see my edit

Comment: double to int comparison should _always_ return false? Even in the case of 1.0 == 1 ?

Comment: @JornVernee yes because that's wrong. if one record has 1, and the other has 1.0...then one can still see that another record might have 1.34 and 1. There's an issue with the table itself at that point.

Comment: I think you should compare numbers as number so you can use rounding and ignore the number decimal places, however if neither object is a number nor can be converted to one, you can compare them as Strings.  Note: I assume you want the Strings `"1"` and `"1.0"` to be equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method for doing exactly the comparison described in the edited question.

```
/**
 * Compare objects for equal value, with some disregard for type.
 * <p>
 * The following types are considered similar, for the purpose of comparing values. The
 * values of the secondary types are converted to the first listed type for value comparison.
 * <ul>
 * <li>{@code long}, {@code int}, {@code short}</li>
 * <li>{@code double} <i>(rounded to 3 decimals before comparing)</i></li>
 * <li>{@code String}, {@code Timestamp}</li>
 * <li>Array <i>(elements are compared using this method, comparison is "deep")</i></li>
 * </ul>
 * Values for all other types are only considered equal if they have the exact same type
 * and {@code equals()} return {@code true}.
 * 
 * @param obj1 the first object to be compared.
 * @param obj2 the second object to be compared.
 * @return {@code true} only if the specified objects are equals according to the rules listed above.
 */
public static boolean equalValue(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
    // Compare null values
    if (obj1 == null)
        return (obj2 == null);
    if (obj2 == null)
        return false;

    Class<?> class1 = obj1.getClass();
    Class<?> class2 = obj2.getClass();

    // Compare double values, rounded to 3 decimal places
    if (class1 == Double.class && class2 == Double.class) {
        // Can't use Math.round() because it doesn't do round-half-up, and may overflow long value-range
        BigDecimal dec1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(((Number)obj1).doubleValue()).setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        BigDecimal dec2 = BigDecimal.valueOf(((Number)obj2).doubleValue()).setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        return dec1.equals(dec2); // equals() is ok, since we know they have same scale
    }

    // Compare arrays
    if (class1.isArray() && class2.isArray()) {
        int len = Array.getLength(obj1);
        if (len != Array.getLength(obj2))
            return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            if (! equalValue(Array.get(obj1, i), Array.get(obj2, i)))
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    // Now that special cases are done, apply simple comparison for values of same type
    if (class1 == class2)
        return obj1.equals(obj2);

    // Compare long/int/short values
    if ((class1 == Long.class || class1 == Integer.class || class1 == Short.class) &&
        (class2 == Long.class || class2 == Integer.class || class2 == Short.class)) {
        return ((Number)obj1).longValue() == ((Number)obj2).longValue();
    }

    // Compare String/Timestamp values
    if ((class1 == String.class || obj1 instanceof Timestamp) &&
        (class2 == String.class || obj2 instanceof Timestamp)) {
        return obj1.toString().equals(obj2.toString());
    }

    return false; // Incomparable types
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toString` **only if** the `toString()` returns the same representation for the same value but of different object types.

For int and long it could be fine **if** the long stays within the range of values an int can be assigned.

If it was double and int it would not be fine for any subset of values due to decimal points etc.

If they are of the same object type the implementation of `equals()` should suffice.

Based off your use cases you can create timestamps off encountered Strings to compare to other timestamps if you have one and compare the ints with each other.

As you will need to represent the bigint as a long, you may aswell just convert the smallint and int values into longs aswell so you can rely on the equals method.

Comment: @Orin2005 if the `long` is outside the `int` range it should be not equal.

Comment: Orin2005 if the long value is outside the range of int, the comparison will work fine without any error. It will just return false.

Answer (score 1):

The notion of "different type, same value" actually is nonsensical. When types are unrelated by a standard conversion (widening, narrowing, [un]boxing, string, ...) then they are, by definition, not comparable. They have different domains of discourse. It's like comparing pounds Avoirdupois to pounds sterling. There isn't a semantic relationship.

You can impose any semantic relationship you want to match your notion of comparability, but this requires that you bring your "values" into a common type, and in a standard way. '1', (int) 1, "1", and new BigDecimal(new BigInteger("1"), 2) might turn into a 'String' in different ways, should you think 'toString()' is your answer, and that may or may not be what you want.

So it is up to you entirely how you render incompatible types comparable. If they're incompatible, you are the one twisting the rules so you have to rule how to twist them. I strongly suggest that you think through the domains you wish to compare, and what twists you plan to handle incompatible comparisons.

Compatible comparisons, of course, should just use the inbuilt mechanisms.

Comment: recreating the tables entirely to have matching datatypes is still my first option. i want to add functionality to my code in case someone who uses this doesn't have matching datatypes. in that case I want to be able account for it. I do see your point though; if they aren't the same type, then they aren't the same. But some people might want to change the types...

Answer (score 0):

If you know all the objects you are comparing are numbers you could convert them to java.math.BigDecimal instances and compare those.

```
Objects.equals(new BigDecimal(a.toString()), new BigDecimal(b.toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects.equals(a, b) calls internally to a.equals(b) if a and b are not null.
a is really of type Long no matter you declared it as Obect, so according to documentation of Long a.equals(b) checks if b is of type long. That's why it return false.
USing toString() doesn't seem the best way to compare numeric objects. 
Try better using methods like longValue(), intValue(), and so on for primitive types comparision.

Comment: I can't seem to call .int/longValue() methods on Object type. I also won't know what type it will be before comparison.